# Tengo el error "Cannot access offset of type string on string" pero nisiquiera estoy trabajando con Arrays, solo con el metodo "post"

Tags: php, html

Me aparece este error

> Cannot access offset of type string on string en la linea 22 ($usuario_acceso=$_POST["txtUsuario"];),

Ni siquiera estoy trabajando con arrays ¿alguien tiene alguna idea? he revisado si podria ser el count de arriba, pero tampoco comentándolo funciona.

```
    require '../modelo/Usuario.php';
    require '../modelo/Acceso.php';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['lastUrl'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( isset($_POST["btn_agregarVecino"])){
        $run_integrante= $_POST["txtRun"];
        $nombre= $_POST["txtNombre"];
        $apellido= $_POST["txtApellido"];
        $fecha_nacimiento= $_POST["txtFechaNac"];
        $estado_civil= $_POST["cmbEstado"];
        $telefono= $_POST["txtTelefono"];
        $correo= $_POST["txtCorreo"];
        $sexo= $_POST["cmbSexo"];
        $etnia= $_POST["cmbEtnia"];
        $ocupacion= $_POST["cmbOcupacion"];
        $discapacidad= $_POST["cmbDiscapacidad"];
        $tipo_socio= $_POST="vecino";
        $estado_socio= "desabilitado";

        $id_acceso= count($_SESSION['arreglo_accesos']);
        $usuario_acceso=$_POST["txtUsuario"]; // Esta linea da error
        $pass_acceso=$_POST["txtPassword"];
        $tipo_usuario="vecino";
        $rut_usuario= $_POST["txtRun"];

        $_Session['datos_acceso']=$rut_usuario;

        $u1= new Usuario($run_integrante,$nombre,$apellido,$fecha_nacimiento,$estado_civil,$telefono,$correo,$sexo,$etnia,$ocupacion,$discapacidad,$tipo_socio,$estado_socio);

        $a1= new Acceso($id_acceso,$usuario_acceso,$pass_acceso,$tipo_usuario,$rut_usuario);
        array_push($_SESSION['arreglo_accesos'],$a1);

        array_push($_SESSION["arreglo_usuarios"],$u1);
        echo "cantidad de registros:", count($_SESSION["arreglo_usuarios"]);

        header("Location:../vistas/login.php" );
    }else{
        header("Location:../vistas/formularios/inicio_admin.php" );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Usa `var_dump($_POST["txtUsuario"]);` a ver que te arroja.

Comment: La variable superglobal $_POST es un `array asociativo` por lo que lo más probable es que no se esté enviando el valor `txtUsuario`.

Answer (score 1):

La variable superglobal `$_POST` es un array asociativo por lo que lo más probable es que no se esté enviando el valor `txtUsuario` por el motivo que sea.

Para evitar esto se puede controlar si existe y si no utilizar un valor por defecto.

```
$usuario_acceso = isset($_POST["txtUsuario"]) ? $_POST["txtUsuario"] : '';
```

De esta manera si no se recibe y no existe esta key en el array `$_POST` no saltará error y cogerá como valor por defecto un string vacío.